# My "return" statement doesn't work

Tags: ruby, return

I've got this method that is supposed to generate a random selection from an array of constants. But the method won't return the results. In fact It won't return anything I try.

Here is the code:

```
COLORS = ["B", "G", "R", "O", "Y", "P"]

class Computer
  attr_reader :random_code

  def initialize
    @random_code = secret_code
  end

  def secret_code

    sample_code = []

    sample_code << COLORS.sample(4)

    return sample_code

  end

  def add(a, b)
    return a + b
  end


end


c = Computer.new

c.add(5, 10)
```

Added the "add" method just to test it out, but it doesn't work aswell. When I say it doesn't work I mean It doesn't show anything in the console.

Comment: You need to tell it to print the result: `puts c.add(5,10)`. Also, you do not need `return` at all. methods automatically return the result of last command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @BroiSatse pointed out, the problem is just that you didn't tell Ruby to print anything to the console.

Here is how I would fix and simplify your code:

```
class Computer
  COLORS = ["B", "G", "R", "O", "Y", "P"]

  attr_reader :random_code

  def initialize
    @random_code = secret_code
  end

  def secret_code
    COLORS.sample(4)
  end

  def add(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end

c = Computer.new
puts c.add(5, 10)
```

A couple other things worth noting:

1. If `COLORS` is something inherent to your Computer class, you can pull it into the class and make it a class constant. You can refer to `COLORS` as-is from within the class, but just remember that if you want to refer to `COLORS` anywhere outside of the class definition, you have to refer to it as `Computer::COLORS` in order to access it. The way you have it currently is fine too, this is just a minor code organization thing.
2. Your `secret_code` function can be simplified to just `COLORS.sample(4)`. In Ruby, you don't have to use the `return` keyword, and it's idiomatic to leave it out whenever it's not needed. The last value in a function definition is what is returned. Also, since `Array#sample` already returns an array, there is no need to define an empty Array `[]` and add to it.

Comment: Wow, really appreciate the help!

Comment: `secret_code` while I think your modification is more the desired result I think it fair to mention that the OP's method will return an `Array` inside an `Array` where as yours is a flat `Array` through `#sample`

Comment: Whoops -- very true! Thanks for pointing that out. You could always do something like `[COLORS.sample(4)]` or `[] << COLORS.sample(4)` if you want a nested array.